# Do I need a pump for my water heater discharge pipe?

Tags: water, heater

I was wondering do I need a special upflow pump for the hot water discharge on my water heater. I have a finished basement and want to set it up so if the heater blows off it will pump outside. My concern is, do I need a special upflow pump to handle the hot water. Thanks

Comment: Do you already have a sump or drywell in your basement, or does your main drain run subslab?

Comment: Voting to close. Questions remain unanswered and OP hasn't been back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too old.

Answer (score 1):

If the safety valve blows off due to over pressure and to a greater degree from overheating the discharge from that safety valve is usually  quick and violent. I hope that the pump and reservoir is of adequate size to hold a large amount of water and steam/water vapor. A special pump for this event is not necessary, just make sure it has a large pumping capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be determined by knowing two values, 1)TPR valve temp limit and the maximum operating temperature of your lift pump. Both values will be available from the device manufacturer and should be indicated on the device rating plates as well. In short, just make sure your pump has a higher temp rating than the TPR valve.